# Facing error while populating dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

m trying to add some `<option>` in existing `<select>` dynamically, but facing error `"An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist."` i have tried to resolve it failed...

**HTML code:**

```
<label class="control-label" for="selectError">Ayat/Hadith no.:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <select id="ayat_selector"  disabled >
          <option id="all_ayat" selected>All </option>                                  
      </select>
  </div>
```

**javascript :**

```
var selectHTML = "<option id='200'>Select Surah</option>";
        alert("ajax going ");
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Surah_CRUD/Load_Surahs",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: '',
            success: function (result) {
                var mera_obj = result.key;
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    selectHTML += "<option id='" + i + "'>" + mera_obj[i].Surah_Description + "</option>";
                }
                var qa = document.getElementById('ayat_selector');
                qa.appendChild(selectHTML);
                alert("done"+qa.className);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("3>  " + thrownError);
            },
        });
```

Comment: code does not show any error if i comment out the line where i am getting element 'ayat_selector'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to select an element by id that isn't exist.
try to change this:

```
var qa = document.getElementById('surah_selector');
```

to this:

```
var qa = document.getElementById('ayat_selector');
```

**UPDATE**

try to change this

```
var qa = document.getElementById('ayat_selector');
qa.appendChild(selectHTML);
alert("done"+qa.className);
```

With this code in jQuery:

```
$('#ayat_selector').append(selectHTML);
alert('done');
```

Comment: I have update the answer with a solution in jQuery try now please @BaqerNaqvi